# python regex relace for wildcard

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to apply regex on python for following code.

```
Country_name = "usa_t1_usq_t1_[0-9]*.csv"
new_result = re.sub(r'(?:_[[0-9-]+].*[a-zA-Z])+', '', Country_name)

# Display the Content
print(new_result)
```

The problem here is its working for above input, but not working for input without [0-9] pattern (3rd input in below example).
for example:

**input** - usa_t1_usq_t1_[0-9]*.csv  **Expected output** - usa_t1_usq_t1

**input** - usa_t1_usq_t1_[0-9]*.gzip.csv  **Expected output** - usa_t1_usq_t1

**input** - usa_t1_usq_t1.gzip.csv  **Expected output** - usa_t1_usq_t1

can someone help me to make proper regex for the above scenario as I am new to regex world ?

Comment: why don't you just split on last underscore? `Country_name.rsplit('_', 1)[0]`?

Comment: will it satisfy third example ?

Comment: Are `[0-9]*` wildcards or plain chars in filenames?

Comment: its wildcard characters

Comment: @BigD oh i didn't see that example, i thought all will follow same pattern

Comment: [regex101](https://regex101.com/) is a great site showing how the regex works. Have fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC,

```py
inputs = ['usa_t1_usq_t1_[0-9]*.csv', 'usa_t1_usq_t1_[0-9]*.gzip.csv', 'usa_t1_usq_t1.gzip.csv']
for Country_name in inputs:
    result = re.sub('(_\[0\-9\]\*)?(\.[a-zA-Z]+)+', '', Country_name)
    print(result)
# usa_t1_usq_t1
# usa_t1_usq_t1
# usa_t1_usq_t1
```

`(_\[0\-9\]\*)` matches the plain string `_[0-9]*` in `Country_name`, and `?` after this means it appears zero or one times.

`(\.[a-zA-Z]+)` matches the suffix starting with `.`, and another `+` means it may appear more than once.

Comment: This will not satisfy  input -  usa_t1_usq_t1_[0-9]*.csv. Sorry its wildcard for me, however we need to consider its as plain chars

Comment: You said `[0-9]*` is not plain chars.

Comment: my bad - Sorry its wildcard for me, however we need to consider its as plain chars

Comment: Ok. If it is a plain string, use `(_\[0\-9\]\*)*(\.[a-zA-Z]+)+`.